# Printing multiple lists using .format in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone shed light on this issue I'm having with Python 3.4.2?

I have two lists, and I want to print specific items within each list using the .format(). Here's the code:

```
names=["Conan", "Belit", "Valeria"]
ages=[25, 21, 22]

print("{0} is {1} years old. Whereas {1} is {0} years old.".format(*names, *ages))
```

I was under the impression that to call specific items in a list, the *listname needs to be used. It works for an individual list:

```
print("{0}".format(*names))
```

But not when I call multiple lists? I've tried both list names with an asterisk, both without, plus signs and so on with no luck. All I seem to get are various syntax errors and such?

All I need it to do is simply print:

> Conan is 21 years old. Whereas Belit is 25 years old.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance. Just can't seem to think my way around this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Additional Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) was added in Python 3.5, so you can't use multiple asterisks `*` in a function call in Python 3.4. It also doesn't work with `str.format` as you want, since calling

```
print("{0} is {1} years old. Whereas {1} is {0} years old.".format(*names, *ages))
```

would be like calling it with the unpacked lists:

```
print("{0} is {1} years old. Whereas {1} is {0} years old.".format(
    "Conan", "Belit", "Valeria", 25, 21, 22))
```

so this prints:

```
Conan is Belit years old. Whereas Belit is Conan years old.
```

---

You could instead just pass the two lists and then use the index behind the field name inside the replacement field, e.g. `{0}` means the first arg that was passed to `format` (so the `names` list in this case) and `{0[0]}` would be the first item in the list.

```
print("{0[0]} is {1[0]} years old. Whereas {0[1]} is {1[1]} years old.".format(
    names, ages))
# Or use keyword arguments.
print("{names[0]} is {ages[0]} years old. Whereas {names[1]} is {ages[1]} years old.".format(
    names=names, ages=ages))
```

Comment: Marvellous, thanks very much skrx - worked like a charm. It was really beginning to get up my nose.